# hashmap vs array of arrays for this instance

Tags: c, arrays, hashmap

I am using C programming language and wanted to ask this quick question. Let's say I have data structures like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char* tag;
    char* name;
    unsigned int id;
} object;
```

in other languages you could create a hashmap that holds keys and value pairs and just throw them in there. C doesn't have a built in hashmap but I was thinking that I could go use some third party hashmap library but that might be overkill for my use case.

Basically I'd like to have some way to access some amount of these either by tag or id; with an array or pointers and a variable for size of this array, I could pretty much add to the list, sort by id or tag or do pretty much what I'd like to do in C without a third party library.

```
typedef struct {
    object** objects;
    unsigned int count;
} object_bag;
```

simple function to add, no duplicate checking etc...

```
void add_object(object* obj) {
     int count = objects->count++;
     objects[count] = calloc(1,sizeof(object*));
     objects[count] = obj;
}
```

In this case, would there be any reason to use a hashmap? This isn't a performance optimization issue, I am just curious as well but would there be a point at which this data structure would become more troublesome than a hashmap?

Comment: How do you access by tag/name using this approach?

Comment: The main point in using a map is constant time access given its key. It all depends on how you need to access your data

Comment: Also note that your memory allocation isn't correct

Comment: Depending on the amount of data you have to manage, but if there is not so many object, then a simple array, with basic management, even without sorting the elements could be useful. Don't try to make premature optimization, use some light abstraction so that you will be able to use more complex efficient structure after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the immediate problem i see with your provided code, is that you need to allocate some space for your **whole** *array of pointers* (`objects`) [at least you left out this part of the code].

It seems like you try to allocate space for a single array cell one at a time, which is not how arrays work. (arrays need to be a single continuous piece of memory, so you need to allocate the whole array up front) (see Johan's hint below)

if you want to support a collection of arbitrary size, be ready to reallocate some space in case you store more objects than you previously allocated space for pointers.

since you do not seem to need "random access" capabilities to the array, you might instead choose to use a "linked list" implementation. It has the property to be easier to grow (just allocate a new element and link it to the end).

if you develop on posix you might want to use the "built-in" `sys/queue.h` linked lists implementations: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html

if i were you, i would most likely reuse a readily available library to be able to use the most appropriate data structure in the first hand. if you do application development, glib might be a good choice: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html

Comment: I thought the same thing regarding allocating space for "object_bag". But it should also be noted that "object" uses pointers. This means when the value of the pointer gets out of scope, you can't access the value anymore. For example generating the content of "object" in a for loop and putting it in "object_bag" will give an pointer error when you try to access the value outside the loop (unless allocated).

Comment: @JohanWentholt oh, I glanced over this, of course allocating space for a "pointer" does not suffice to store the actual object's content. thx!

Comment: I initially left out the allocation of the bags object. I would prefer constant time access to the memory because I will know when new objects are being added to the list or swapping values around. For removing I could set the index to some value, loop through the array and free the memory allocated for that object. The thing is currently I do not know how large this application will grow, i'd say there's no need for more than 200 objects now. Looking at glib from gnome, could I just use their glib.h with my program?

Comment: @user1610950 for ~200 objects performance gains or losses will not be noticable for a single user interactive application. a handy approach for deleting objects from an array list, is to take the last list entry, and put it in the hole, where the deleted object was, so your array stays nicely continuously filled. for integrating glib you need to add headers when compiling & add libraries when linking. If you are confident that you can create a functional array list implementation in acceptable time and performance is not critical you might very well go with your proposed array list approach.